# Can you use Windows to develop, build, and publish .NET Core 2.0 services for a Ubuntu based Service Fabric Cluster?

Tags: azure, microservices, service-fabric-stateless, azure-service-fabric

I would like to build .NET Core 2.0 services for a Ubuntu based Service Fabric on my windows machine. From the docs, it seems like I can't use Visual Studios to do this.

Does anyone know the workflow for developing, building, and publishing services in this way? Can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Anything you compile targeting .NET Core will run on any of the platforms supported by .NET Core. However, there is no built-in publishing support, that would be a separate operation you'd have to set up yourself.

You can find the list of currently supported platforms on the [Runtime Identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) page. The current Ubuntu list is:

> - ubuntu.14.04-x64
> - ubuntu.14.10-x64
> - ubuntu.15.04-x64
> - ubuntu.15.10-x64
> - ubuntu.16.04-x64
> - ubuntu.16.10-x64

Comment: Have you been able to deploy a .NET Core stateless service on a Ubuntu service fabric? If so, what was your workflow?

Comment: I have not, but check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-app-to-party-cluster#deploy-the-app-to-the-service-fabric-cluster) new article, it looks like you should be able to do this now from within Visual Studio. (Pretty much the same publish workflow for pushing any other Azure project type to a given subscription/resource target.)